# Writing PDO DELETE query values

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, sql-delete

I was wondering if we can still use **values** from a freshly `DELETE` **row** as a `SELECT` or do we really need to `SELECT` it before ?

**Example :**
Transform this

```
$foo = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id= :id");
$foo->execute(array(
    "id" => $table_id
));
$foo = $foo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$delete_foo = $bdd->prepare("DELETE FROM table WHERE id = :id");
$delete_foo->execute(array(
    "id" => $table_id
));
echo $foo['name'] . " has been deleted !";
```

Into this :

```
$delete_foo = $bdd->prepare("DELETE FROM table WHERE id = :id");
$delete_foo->execute(array(
    "id" => $table_id
));
$delete_foo = $delete_foo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $delete_foo['name'] . " has been deleted !";
```

It would be easier. I was just wondering, I use the 1st method but it just went in mind and I don't find answers.

Comment: Why don't you just do `echo "$value has been deleted !";`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-delete.html), there is a proprietary extension to the delete statement called `RETURNING`. [Sql Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) provides something similar, they call it OUTPUT

> For example, OUTPUT DELETED.* in the following DELETE statement
>   returns all columns deleted from the ShoppingCartItem table:

```
DELETE Sales.ShoppingCartItem  
    OUTPUT DELETED.*;
```

Unfortunately, mysql *does not* have anything like the above. If you delete a row it's gone (unless you roll back the transaction instead of commiting). If you want to Select the data, you need to execute the SELECT before the DELETE

Answer (score 1):

`DELETE` queries wont return any results (besides rows affected), so a `PDO::query` wont have any usable data to fetch.

Answer (score 1):

For the example provided, an extra select query just makes no sense. As you have your $value already.

I would rather say that you need to simplify your PDO code at whole. Compare the below code snippet with yours

```
$foo = $db->run("SELECT foo FROM table WHERE value = ?", [$value])->fetchColumn();
$db->run("DELETE FROM table WHERE value = ?", [$value]);
echo "$foo has been deleted!";
```

the run() function can be achieved by a very small PDO modification:

```
class MyPDO extends PDO
{
    public function run($sql, $args = NULL)
    {
        $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($args);
        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

the code is taken from my  article, [Simple yet efficient PDO wrapper](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper)